# docker container linux-tools-generic package

Tags: linux, docker, performance-monitoring, packages

My goal is to use `perf` to run performance tests on some Docker images. By default, the images I'm using don't come with `perf`. As such, I tried

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-tools-generic
```

to get perf, but I got

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-generic
```

I asked on SO, and was told that my `sources.list` might not be set up properly, and was also sent here because my confusion better pertains to SF.

Any advice on how I can get/run `perf` inside various Docker containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install linux-tools-generic
```

didn't work, I got a different solution to work for me. I'd done

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-tools
```

Which I realized gave me perf_4.9. A softlink later, `perf` now works inside a docker container. It's not the kernel specific one, but it works for what I need (so far).

Answer (score 0):

`centos`:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ docker run -it centos
[root@ae6c1eb43a15 /]# yum --assumeyes --quiet install perf
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/packages/numactl-libs-2.0.9-7.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
Public key for numactl-libs-2.0.9-7.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed
Public key for perf-3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed
Importing GPG key 0xF4A80EB5:
 Userid     : "CentOS-7 Key (CentOS 7 Official Signing Key) <security@centos.org>"
 Fingerprint: 6341 ab27 53d7 8a78 a7c2 7bb1 24c6 a8a7 f4a8 0eb5
 Package    : centos-release-7-5.1804.el7.centos.2.x86_64 (@Updates)
 From       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
[root@ae6c1eb43a15 /]# perf --version
perf version 3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64.debug
[root@ae6c1eb43a15 /]#
```

`ubuntu`:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ docker run -it ubuntu bash
root@98214d8d539f:/#
root@98214d8d539f:/# apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install linux-tools-generic         
.....
root@98214d8d539f:/# perf
```